# How to resolve this issue "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)"?

Tags: python, valueerror

How to resolve this issue "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)"?

```py
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
data = load_breast_cancer()

label_names = data['target_names']
labels = data['target']
feature_names = data['feature_names']
features = data['data']
print(label_names)
print(labels[0])
print(feature_names[0])
print(features[0])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

The error occurs on the following line:

```py
train, test, train_labels, test_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features,labels,test_size =   0.40, random_state = 42)
```

Comment: Hi Tahmid and welcome on Stack Overflow, 

Please, read your code twice before posting a question. Your error was trivial, you have a duplicated variable in the list of variables you are unpacking. You could have get this easily. Be aware that your question could be downvoted for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your function "train_test_split" only returns 4 values. Modify your line like this:

```
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features,labels,test_size =   0.40, random_state = 42)
```